# Swift `in` keyword meaning?

Tags: ios, swift, keyword

I am trying to implement some code from parse.com and I notice a keyword `in` after the void.

I am stumped what is this ? The second line you see the `Void in`

```
PFUser.logInWithUsernameInBackground("myname", password:"mypass") {
  (user: PFUser?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
  if user != nil {
    // Do stuff after successful login.
  } else {
    // The login failed. Check error to see why.
  }
}
```

The docs don't document this. I know the `in` keyword is used in `for` loops.

Anyone confirm?

Comment: before the "in" is the signature of the closure. After the in is the body of the closure.

Comment: http://www.apeth.com/swiftBook/ch02.html#_anonymous_functions

Comment: Look up "Closure Expression Syntax" in [The Swift Programming Language](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Closures.html)

Answer (score 113, accepted):

In a named function, we declare the parameters and return type in the `func` declaration line.

```
func say(s:String)->() {
    // body
}
```

In an anonymous function, there is no `func` declaration line - it's anonymous! So we do it with an `in` line at the start of the body instead.

```
{
    (s:String)->() in
    // body
}
```

(That is the *full* form of an anonymous function. But then Swift has a series of rules allowing the return type, the parameter types, and even the parameter names and the whole `in` line to be omitted under certain circumstances.)

Comment: Thanks matt, i can't believe i missed that one. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: I am looking for a standard for how to format the code. I prefer that the `{` and the parameters, return type, and `in` go on the same line after the command to which they apply. But with spaces between all of those. I thought about putting the param and in on the next line, but then they are aligned with the code in the block. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 25):

The question of what purpose `in` serves has been well-answered by other users here; in summary: `in` is a keyword defined in the Swift closure syntax as a separator between the function type and the function body in a closure:

> { /*parameters and type*/ `in` /*function body*/ }

But for those who might be wondering "but why specifically the keyword `in`?", here's a bit of history shared by Joe Groff, Senior Swift Compiler Engineer at Apple, on the [Swift forums](https://forums.swift.org/t/history-why-does-closure-syntax-use-the-keyword-in/21885):

> It's my fault, sorry. In the early days of Swift, we had a closure
> syntax that was very similar to traditional Javascript:
>
> ```
> func (arg: -> Type, arg: Type) -> Return { ... }
> ```
>
> While this is nice and regular syntax, it is of course also very bulky
> and awkward if you're trying to support expressive functional APIs,
> such as map/filter on collections, or if you want libraries to be able
> to provide closure-based APIs that feel like extensions of the
> language.
>
> Our earliest adopters at Apple complained about this, and mandated
> that we support Ruby-style trailing closure syntax. This is tricky to
> fit into a C-style syntax like Swift's, and we tried many different
> iterations, including literally Ruby's `{|args| }` syntax, but many of
> them suffered from ambiguities or simply distaste and revolt from our
> early adopters. We wanted something that still looked like other parts
> of the language, but which could be parsed unambiguously and could
> span the breadth of use cases from a fully explicit function signature
> to extremely compact.
>
> We had already taken `in` as a keyword, we couldn't use `->` like Java
> does because it's already used to denote the return type, and we were
> concerned that using `=>` like C# would be too visually confusing. `in`
> made `xs.map { x in f(x) }` look vaguely like `for x in xs { f(x) }`,
> and **people hated it less than the alternatives**.

*Formatting and emphasis mine. And thanks to [Nikita Belov's post](https://forums.swift.org/t/documentation-or-explanation-for-keyword-in-as-used-in-function-arguments/34517/6) on the Swift forums for helping my own understanding.

Comment: "and people hated it less than the alternatives."  is the validation I needed today. 

"In" is an adverb trying to take the place of a preposition here.  "From" would have made much more sense to use.

Comment: Not to be a pedant, but "in" is definitely being used as a preposition here (otherwise, which "verb" is it modifying?). Also, `from` would be backwards: it's the expression `f(x)` that comes from the parameter `x`, not the other way around.

Comment: My favorite takeaway from the docs: "It’s always possible to infer the parameter types and return type when passing a closure to a function or method as an inline closure expression. As a result, you never need to write an inline closure in its fullest form when the closure is used as a function or method argument."

Comment: Such a great reference to Ruby! Thanks!

Answer (score 19):

Closure expression syntax has the following general form:

[image: Closure Expression Syntax]