# Swift anonymous function ends in 'in'

Tags: ios, swift, closures, anonymous-function

I'm following a tutorial that uses 'in' like this: `let completion = {(error: Error?) in }`.  I was searching and found a closely similar answer on stackoverflow but it doesn't touch on if the body ends with 'in' so I'm confused because I was thinking 'in' signifies that a new function body was coming next.  Here is the originating stack overflow resource I found: [Similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30379108/swift-in-keyword-in-a-on-a-function/35233199)

Here is the full implementation of how its being used so far inside a test:

```
func testLogin_MakesRequestWithUsernameAndPassword() {

        let sut = APIClient()

        let mockURLSession = MockURLSession()

        sut.session = mockURLSession

        let completion = {(error: Error?) in }

        sut.loginUserWithName("dasdom", password: "1234", completion: completion)

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right that closure body should appear after `in`. However, you are forgetting that function/closure body can be *empty*, therefore this is completely valid, similar to declaring a function with an empty body:

```
func doSomething() {
}
```

With closures it is also common to write `{ _ in }` to prevent the compiler from warning you about unused parameter.