# How to set the background color of a swiftui to lightGray?

Tags: swift, swiftui, swift5

I am currently trying to set the background color of a text field in SwiftUI to light gray. it is not working

my code is this

```swift
TextField("Enter Your Email", text: $username)
    .background(Color.lightGray)
```

Any idea what could be wrong with it ? It works when i just use "gray" But i need the color to be lighter than that. I looked up lightGray in swift , and it says it is a color.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You can set the background by adding `.padding()` to the `TextField` and then using `UIColor.lightGray`. Setting the `.padding()` isn't required, however it makes it look a little more native when setting a background color.

```
TextField("Enter Your Email", text: $text)
    .padding()
    .background(Color(UIColor.lightGray))
```

Comment: yeah, But i will need it to be light gray, thats my question. I know how to make it gray, but lightGray doesn't work

Comment: @user10511525 I would recommend asking a separate question rather than asking in the comments. https://stackoverflow.com/a/30379166/264802

Answer (score 29):

Can also use `.background(Color(.systemGray6))`

Comment: This is also SwiftUI's default color for List views using the `InsetGroupedListStyle()`

Answer (score 12):

I also sometimes adjust the color of Gray like so:

```
.background(
    Color.gray
        .brightness(0.4)
)
```

or

```
.background(
    Color.gray
        .opacity(0.1)
)
```

Comment: Setting the brightness was what I needed!

Answer (score 6):

There is no `lightGray` color in `Color`, but you can use `.background(Color.init(UIColor.lightGray))`

Comment: Thank you so much! I spent hours searching and no solution.

Comment: @fuzz, I saw your answer before it was edited and there was another code. but than you edited it, just after I wrote my solution